# Inferred type in a Scala program

Tags: scala, type-inference, read-eval-print-loop

The Scala REPL shows the inferred type of an expression. Is there a way to know the inferred type in a normal Scala program ?

For example,

```
val x = {
//some Scala expressions
}
```

Now I want to know the actual type of x.

Comment: `val x : String = { }` is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes in some cases it's easy to know what the inferred type (in this case String) but some other cases it could me more complicated.

Comment: So you wanna check what type it is at runtime? Like `if(x.isInstanceOf[String])`?

Comment: No I want to program to print that the inferred type is String, like it does on the REPL.

Comment: im sorry, im not too familiar with REPL. From what I saw, it prints out the type like `x: java.lang.String = abc`, am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) is what you are looking for?

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def typeOf[T](x:T)( implicit tag: TypeTag[T] ) = tag
typeOf: [T](x: T)(implicit tag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

scala> class Foo( a:Int )
defined class Foo

scala> trait Bar
defined trait Bar

scala> val x = new Foo(3) with Bar
x: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@62fb343d

scala> val t = typeOf(x)
t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Foo with Bar] = TypeTag[Foo with Bar]

scala> t.tpe
res20: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo with Bar

scala> t.tpe.toString
res21: String = Foo with Bar
```

And just to demonstrate that it yields the static type of the expression rather than the dynamic type of the object:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val s:Seq[Int] = l
s: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> typeOf(s)
res22: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Seq[Int]] = TypeTag[scala.Seq[Int]]
```

Comment: What does the Scala REPL use internally ?

Comment: The REPL existed long before TypeTags were introduced, so at least at one time the REPL didn't use them.  I don't know much about the implementation of the REPL, but clearly it compiles the code you enter; perhaps the type information is part of what the compiler API makes available.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want to know is whether what you will get from TypeTag is the same result you would get from the REPL, or some other type-like information.  They are the same; when you use TypeTag as we did here, the compiler just creates a TypeTag object containing the type information produced during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the expression is known statically at compile time.

To access it at runtime, you could use a `TypeTag` as in the other answer, or a trivial macro:

```
scala> import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.language.experimental.macros

scala> import reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

scala> def impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[String] = { import c.universe._
     | c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(c.typecheck(x.tree.duplicate).tpe.toString))) }
impl: (c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context)(x: c.Expr[Any])c.Expr[String]

scala> def f(x: =>Any) = macro impl
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
defined term macro f: (x: => Any)String

scala> trait A; trait B extends A; trait C extends A
defined trait A
defined trait B
defined trait C

scala> f(List(new B{}, new C{}))
res2: String = List[A]
```

The REPL also just reports the type assigned to an expression tree by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

when using Metals with Scala, you can hover over the `x` variable in your expression and the type is then instantly displayed (having compiled your program), or your enable `Metals: Toggle showing inferred type` then the type is directly shown in grey color beside the variable name while hovering over with the mouse.